getprogramaccounts with filter on symbol ? (token 2022)
I'm using token 2022 with metadata pointer extension, and the metadata are held in the mint account.
I would like to fetch all mint addresses with a particular symbol, i know how to construct this kind of request, but i don't know how to find the position of "symbol" in the data for my filter.
I found the structure of metadata here : https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/17a228bb8e36737209ca5d5375415c70da37c311/token-metadata/js/src/state.ts#L20
So at least there are 2*32 for auth and mint, but i can't find the size of "name".
And i'm not sure if it really starts at 0 for the struct above, since it's the same account that holds the metadata and token info (freeze auth, etc)

Unfortunately, you can't do this using a filter on getProgramAccounts, since the metadata information can be in different places in the mint account. This is why other programs like Metaplex maintain fixed offsets for the metadata structure.
Instead, you'll need to fetch all of the mint accounts by looking for byte 165 to equal 1 (AccountType::Mint from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/933ae6c0cba427b6ac342b40fa55da436953ab7d/token/program-2022/src/extension/mod.rs#L1029), and then deserialize each one client-side, looking for the symbol, ie:
let mint = StateWithExtensions::<Mint>::unpack(&account.data).unwrap();
if let Ok(metadata_bytes) = mint.get_extension_bytes::<TokenMetadata>() {
    let metadata = TokenMetadata::try_from_slice(metadata_bytes).unwrap();
    if metadata.symbol == "SYMBOL TO SEARCH FOR" {
        // do the thing that I want
    }
}

Adapted from a test at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/933ae6c0cba427b6ac342b40fa55da436953ab7d/token/program-2022-test/tests/token_metadata_initialize.rs#L134

answer accepted "actually i can't do it with getProgramAccounts", thanks
